# buttons are not show assigning to vaules to graphing calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I not sure if this supper basic or not but I am trying to add number values to some buttons through onclick functions. All done in html and javascript.

It can display the numbers fine but doesn't seem to make the numbers have any values to them if that makes sense. I just keep getting null values. Is it because of all the onclick events?

Below is the html.

```js
var getvaule7.value = document.getElementsByClassName("7");

getvaule7.value = 7;

var getvaule8 = document.getElementsByClassName("8");

getvaule8.value = 8;

var getvaule9 = document.getElementsByClassName("9");

getvaule9.value = 9;

var getvaule4 = document.getElementsByClassName("4");

getvaule4.value = 4;

var getvaule5 = document.getElementsByClassName("5");

getvaule5.value = 5;

var getvaule6 = document.getElementsByClassName("6");

getvaule6.value = 6;

var getvaule1 = document.getElementsByClassName("1");

getvaule1.value = 1;

var getvaule2 = document.getElementsByClassName("2");

getvaule2.value = 2;

var getvaule3 = document.getElementsByClassName("3");

getvaule3.value = 3;

var getvaule0 = document.getElementsByClassName("0");

getvaule0.value = 0;

function number7() {       
    document.getElementById("show").value = getvaule7.value;
}
console.log(number7());

function number8() {
    document.getElementById("show").value = getvaule8.value;

}

function number9() {
    document.getElementById("show").value = getvaule9.value;
}

function number4() {
    document.getElementById("show").value = getvaule4.value;
}

function number5() {
    document.getElementById("show").value = getvaule5.value;
}

function number6() {
    document.getElementById("show").value = getvaule6.value;
}

function number1() {
    document.getElementById("show").value = getvaule1.value;
}

function number2() {
    document.getElementById("show").value = getvaule2.value;
}

function number3() {
    document.getElementById("show").value = getvaule3.value;
}

function number0() {
   document.getElementById("show").value = getvaule0.value;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">
      Graphing Calculator from Scratch
    </h1>

    <div id="Text box" style="text-align: center;">

        <input type="text" name="" id="show">
        
        

    </div>
    <br></br>
    <div style="text-align:center" id="click-row">
    <div id="row one" ><button type="button" class="7" onclick="number7()" value=7> 7</button> 
        <button type="button"  class="8" onclick="number8()" >8</button> 
        <button type="button" class="9" onclick="number9()">9</button> 
        </div>
        <div id="row two"><button type="button" class="4" onclick="number4()">4</button> 
            <button type="button" class="5" onclick="number5()">5</button> 
            <button type="button" class="6"  onclick="number6()">6</button> 
            </div>
            <div id="row three"><button type="button" class="1" onclick="number1()">1</button> 
                <button type="button" class="2" onclick="number2()">2</button> 
                <button type="button" class="3" onclick="number3()">3</button> 
                </div>
                
                 
                <button type="button" class="0" onclick="number0()">0</button> 
                <button type="button" class=".">.</button> 
                <button type="button" class=""></button>
               
               
                <div id="row 5">
                    <div id="row 5"><button type="button" class="+/-">+/-</button> 
                        <div id="row 5"><button type="button" class="+">+</button>
                            <div id="row 5"><button type="button" class="-">-</button>   
                    <button type="button" onclick="enter()" >=</button> 
                    
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <button onclick="document.getElementById('show').value = ''" style="text-align:center;">Clear input field</button>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
            </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clearify what you are exactly want to do, not whole file, just the problematic parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the way you are going about it is not the best way to do it but since you are just getting started I will not confuse you and just correct your code instead.

There are a couple of errors in your code

- button does not have value it has innerText property. value property
  is for input tags only.
- use += when you are trying to set value to
  show input since = will erase what was in it before hands.
- you have not defined enter() function that was it gives you that error you
  have to create enter function first
- another thing is document.getElementsByClassName("7") does not retun one element like getElementById but it returns an array that is why if you are using gelementsByClassName you have to also write [number] where number is the index of your element in the returned array. in your case number is 0 which means the first element in the array.

another one is you dont need to use getValue7.value = document.get... since you are using it just for storing the element you can just use getValue = document.getlE.....

and you html tag nesting was incorrect please nest them correctly.

To help you understand the correct solution. I wrote minimum code for you project down below. please compare it with your code to see what is wrong,

```js
var  getvaule7 =document.getElementsByClassName("7")[0];
var  getvaule8 =document.getElementsByClassName("8")[0];
var  getvaule9 =document.getElementsByClassName("9")[0];
var  getPlus = document.getElementsByClassName("plus")[0];

function number7(){
    document.getElementById("show").value += getvaule7.innerText;
}

function number8(){
    document.getElementById("show").value += getvaule7.innerText;
}

function number9(){
    document.getElementById("show").value += getvaule7.innerText;
}

function plus(){
    document.getElementById("show").value += getPlus.innerText;
}

function enter(){
    document.getElementById("show").value = eval(document.getElementById("show").value);
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">
    Graphing Calculator from Scratch
</h1>
<div id="Text box" style="text-align: center;">
  <input type="text" name="" id="show"> 
</div>
<br></br>
<div style="text-align:center" id="click-row">
    <div id="row one" >
      <button type="button" class="7" onclick="number7()" value=7>7</button> 
      <button type="button"  class="8" onclick="number8()" >8</button> 
      <button type="button" class="9" onclick="number9()">9</button> 
</div>

               
<div id="row 5">
  <button type="button" onclick="plus()" class="plus">+</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="enter()" >=</button>   
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('show').value = ''" style="text-align:center;">Clear input field</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function load() {
                      
                        
                    let num7=document.getElementById("7").addEventListener('click',()=>{
                        document.querySelector(".show").value+=7;
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                        
                      

                    })
                     
                        
                    let num8=document.getElementById("8").addEventListener('click',()=>{
                        document.querySelector(".show").value+=8;
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                       
                        
                      

                    })
                  
                  
                        
                            var userEnter1= parseInt(document.querySelector(".show").value);

                            var userEnter2=parseInt(document.querySelector(".show").value);
                           [0]
                        // HOW TO MAKE SURE THAT A USER CAN INPUT ANOTHER DATA AFTER PRESSING THE + 
                       
                     
                        
                     let add=document.getElementById("add").addEventListener('click',()=>{
                        document.querySelector(".show").value+="+";
                       
                        userEnter1+userEnter2;
                       
                       
                        
                      

                    }) 


                      
                    


                    const equals=document.getElementById("equals").addEventListener('click',()=>{
                       
                    console.log(  userEnter1+userEnter2); 
});
                        




                        

                        

                        

                       
                       


                      

                }
                window.onload = load;
```

```css
                        

                        

                        

                       
                       


                      

                }
                window.onload = load;
```

```html
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">
      Graphing Calculator from Scrach  
    </h1>

    <div id="Text box" style="text-align: center;">

        <input type="text" class="show" id="clear">
        
        

    </div>
    <br></br>
    <div style="text-align:center" id="click-row">
    <div id="activate" >
        <div id="row one">
        <input type="Button"  id="7"  class="num7" value="7"  >  </input>
        <input type="Button"  id="8"   value="8"  >  </input>
        
    </div>

    <div id="row 2">
        <input type="Button"  id="add"   value="+" onclick="" >  </input>
        <input type="Button"  id="equals"   value="="  >  </input>
      
    </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <button onclick="document.getElementById('clear').value = ''" style="text-align:center;">Clear input field</button>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
            </body>
</html>
```